# Помогите пожалуйста найти шрифт

Tags: шрифты

Можно ли как то найти шрифт имея лишь 1 слово написанное этим шрифтом? Если да то скажите как это можно сделать? Или скажите название этого шрифта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просить опознать шрифт, выкладывая текст вместо картинки - гениально

Comment: добавил еще и картинку

Comment: Смахивает на Courier New.

Comment: Да, похоже это действительно он, но каким методом вы это узнали?

Comment: Глазами ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: На картинке похож на `Nimbus Mono PS`

Answer (score 0):

В на странице выставлен набор шрифтов `ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace` чтоб браузер выбрал из тех что есть в наличие в системе. `ui-monospace` в приоритете - выставляет шрифт который установлен по умолчанию - у меня "source code pro regular"

На картинке похож на `Nimbus Mono PS`